# Botão de curtir do facebook demorando para carregar

Tags: jquery, html, facebook

Tenho uma div onde se encontra a parte das redes sociais. Nela tenho botão de curtir do Facebook, do Twitter e do Google Plus.

O do Twitter e do Google Plus terminam de carregar juntos e é mostrado, já o do Facebook demora mais alguns segundos para carregar.

Queria colocar um loader nessa div e quando estiverem carregados ai sim poderá mostrar todos, de uma só vez.

É possível?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro deixe sua `div` principal com `opacity:0`. Depois utilize `Jquery` para verificar se o botão do Facebook foi carregado e por fim faça todos aparecem juntos.

**Exemplo:**

```
$( ".facebook").load(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeTo( "fast" , 1);
});
```

Comment: `$( ".facebook").ready`? Isso não funciona não, só o `document` tem esse evento.

Comment: Realmente, foi um equívoco. Já editei, valeu.

Answer (score 0):

Com a div não tenho certeza se há uma forma. Mas se você usar diretamente o iframe gerado dos respectivos botões você pode delegar um evento de load normalmente para eles como a uma janela comum.

Comment: Não consegui Diego, por gentileza edite esse JSFiddle com sua idéia?  http://jsfiddle.net/C3LMR/

Comment: Jefferson pelo código não são iframes, porém códigos que são carregados por scripts dessas redes. Poderia checar na documentação delas se elas oferecem uma API que possibilite o que procura? A possibilidade de executar uma função quando o script é carregado é suficiente.